# Почему std::basic_ifstream<char16_t> Visual Studio считает deprecated? C++

Tags: c++, fstream

Есть такой простейший код:

```
std::basic_ifstream<char16_t> stream{"path"};
```

И вижла не дает скомпилировать код, потому что внутри std::basic_filebuf используется std::codecvt, который deprecated.
Ошибку выдает такую:

```
warning C4996: 'std::codecvt<char16_t,char,mbstate_t>': warning STL4020: std::codecvt<char16_t, char, mbstate_t>, std::codecvt<char32_t, char, mbstate_t>, std::codecvt_byname<char16_t, char, mbstate_t>, and std::codecvt_byname<char32_t, char, mbstate_t> are deprecated in C++20 and replaced by specializations with a second argument of type char8_t. You can define _SILENCE_CXX20_CODECVT_FACETS_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX20_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.
```

Я не смог решить проблему и попытался хотя бы заглушить варнинги, сделав так, как вказано в сообщении, но это не помогло:

```
#define _SILENCE_CXX20_CODECVT_FACETS_DEPRECATION_WARNING
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: std::basic_ifstream<char16_t> по умолчанию использует      std::char_traits<char>. Вам наверняка нужен  std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char16_t>> stream{"path"}

Comment: @ARHovsepyan https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream - здесь написано, что по умолчанию используется std::char_traits<CharT>. Разве я не прав? Однако попробую

Comment: У меня опечатка: вам нужен std::basic_istream<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>>

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вы меня не поняли. В документации шаблонные параметры определены так:
`template<class CharT, class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>> `. Так что по умолчанию, если передать первым параметром char16_t , то вторым будет std::char_traits<char16_t>. Разве это не так? Какой смысл явно указывать то, что указано по умолчанию?

Comment: Что происходит при объявлении указанного в предупреждении макроса? Какой текст ошибки/предупреждения? Где объявляется макрос по отношению к заголовочным файлам?